# Получить значение из консоли js с помощью Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, парсер

Есть сайт https://tr.tommy.com/erkek-giyim?p=2
Если в консоли разработчика ввести `console.log(impressionList)` - мы получим массив значений.
Вопрос, как с помощью python можно получить эти значения?[image: массив значений]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты пытаешься спарсить данные с сайта по одному из двух причин:

1. воруешь у турков))
2. хочешь научиться обрабатывать инфу с сайта (в учебных целях)

Я помогаю в надежде, что второй случай)

```
view-source:https://tr.tommy.com/erkek-giyim?p=2
```

Тут можно заменить, что данные в эту переменную записываются напрямую)

Можно открыть  питоне эту страницу и спарсить.

Либо просто скопировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

себе в js файл и оттуда в своем проекте пушить в бэк